# How to call Focus on a TreeView from the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

We are using a TreeView control in an MVVM C# WPF application.

I have successfully added Expand/Collapse All functionality to the View - iterating through all the Items in the TreeView, setting IsExpanded and then calling Focus on the TreeView to refresh the changes.

I have also successfully added functionality to clear the currently selected Item in the TreeView when clicking the empty space in the TreeView.

My current task and problem is to automatically select any newly added Items in the TreeView.  The IsSelected and IsExpanded properties of the TreeViewItems are bound to matching properties in the ViewModel and setting IsSelected on the ViewModel works as long as the parent node is expanded.

I have tried setting IsExpanded on the parent ViewModel but as far as I am aware I need to then call Focus on the TreeView to force it to update and expand its representation of the tree.  Since I am in the ViewModel, I have no connection to the TreeView without breaking MVVM.

How can I make this work?

Edit: Source added for pushpraj

The tree items are stored like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> _children = new ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel>();
public ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> Children
{
    get { return _children; }
    set
    {
        _children = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Children", this);
    }
}
```

The Children property of our root node is bound to the ItemsSource property of the TreeView.  The child nodes are added programmatically to the Children property of the root node and each other.

The source I am working with is not my own and I am not overly experienced with WPF so please forgive me if I am giving you the wrong information. I have also noticed that we are using some Drag/Drop functionality in our TreeView from Gong Solutions.  Could this be the cause of our problem?  Setting IsExpanded to true in our ViewModel does not expand the entry in the tree view.

Comment: You don't need to focus neither `TreeView`, nor parent `TreeViewItem` to force `TreeView` to update. If `TreeViewItem.IsExpanded` is bound to corresponding property of view model, just set this property to `true` and add new item into parent view model's collection. If that collection implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` (like `ObservableCollection<T>` does), you'll see new item in `TreeView`.

Comment: @Dennis `IsExpanded` is bound to the corresponding property, I am setting it to `true` before adding the new item and the collection is an `ObservableCollection` but still the parent item does not expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following style in the resources

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
</Style>
```

this will enable every new TreeViewItem to focus itself when created

try it and see if this is what you are looking for

Comment: I have tried adding the style you suggest but still the parent `TreeViewItem` does not expand in the `TreeView` when the new child is added to it and set as the selected item.Have I misunderstood something? I tried adding the `Setter` to the window resources styles and the `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle`

Comment: @MickWaites, above style only helps to focus on the newly added item. In order to expand the parent item, you may simply set IsExpanded to true on the parent item through binding. If you could  share some code how you store the tree items and populate the treeview, perhaps I may give a try for the same.

Comment: I have added info to the original question. Does this help?

Comment: @MickWaites, seems like you need to set parent's IsExpanded to true after adding the new item. if that does not help, could you post a working sample of your app? May I have a look.

Comment: I am setting the parent's IsExpanded after adding the new child. Unfortunately I am not able to post the app, company rules forbid it. Sorry if that prevents you from helping me further.

Comment: @MickWaites, don't be sorry. I understand it may not be feasible to share the code. but appreciated if you could write a small sample which can reproduce this issue. it is not necessary to include full functionality, just minimum to reproduce the issue would be sufficient. I would be really difficult to identify the issue without a working sample.

Comment: I was in the process of creating a stripped down project to recreate the issue when I noticed that the IsExpanded property was not calling the PropertyChanged event whilst IsSelected was.  I corrected this and the problem is fixed.  Thanks for the help - it got me looking in the right direction.

Comment: @MickWaites, Great Find! I am glad to hear that. You may accept this as answer if this helped you achieve your goal. you can always find me through my profile. last but not the least happy coding :)